# How to embed Tcl interpreter in C application and access it used socket?

Tags: c, sockets, tcl, telnet

I want embed Tcl interpreter in C application. And access it used socket.The topology is:

```
PC  -------------  C application(embed Tcl interpreter)
```

**PC**: as a client, send **Tcl script** that used Telnet.
**C application**: as a server, receive Tcl script. And parse it. In Linux.

In C application, the pseudo-code is:

```
char read_buf[1024];
int  ret_read;
while(true)
{
    ...

    ret_read = read(socket_fd, read_buf, 1024); 

    //How to process read_buf before call TCL interpreter APIs?
    //Which Tcl interpreter APIs need call?
}
```

My questions:

1. How to process read_buf before call TCL interpreter APIs?
2. Which Tcl APIs should be used?

   Tcl_EvalObjEx(),
   Tcl_EvalFile(),
   Tcl_EvalObjv(),
   Tcl_Eval(),
   Tcl_EvalEx() **......**

Comment: Try some specific things and if they don't work, then post what you've done (along with what is happening instead) and ask for help.